# AsyncTask returning null

Tags: android, jsoup, asynctaskloader

I'm using jsoup to parse a html code, I'm using obviously an AsyncTask but it's returning null (javanullpointerexception).

```
private class LoadDocument extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document>
    {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Parser.this, "Loading...", "Recuperation donnees...");
        }



        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... url) {
            url[0] = urll;

                try {
                    document = Jsoup.connect(url[0])
                            .data("query", "Java")
                            .userAgent("Mozilla")
                            .cookie("auth", "token")
                            .timeout(10000)
                            .post();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            return document;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
             document=result;
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        }


}
```

And then to execute a task and return the document:

```
urll= //the website
document=new LoadDocument().execute(urll).get();
```

I guess that document is always null. What's going wrong in my code?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: code looking fine you can try to put log inside doInBackground and check what you are getting in document

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K:i put `Log.d("DOCUMENTT",document.toString());` just before the return statement and it's not executed.

Comment: see my answer. Jsoup has a method for that toString();

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code. Please log it with `Document.text();` Can you try changing the one line to check: doc = `Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com").get();` then use `Document.text()` in your log.

Comment: `Log.d("DOCUMENT",document.text());` just after the `execute(url).get()` and nothing is displayed. Compiler does not arrive in that line.

Comment: Your using execute(url).post() , not .get(), there different.

Comment: yes, in `doInBackground` I'm using post(), and to have the document I'm using get(). You can notice that in my code above.

Comment: My bad, I though your .get() meaning the HTTP method.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask.execute()` doesn't return the result. Instead it returns a reference to the task itself. The result is only available to the `onPostExecute` method once the task completed.

Comment: And i think that `execute(URL).get()` returns result value, no ?

Comment: Oops, you are right, `get()` waits for the task to finish and retrieves the result. Although this pretty much defeats the purpose of an `AsyncTask`. It doesn't make sense to start the work in the background and then block to wait until it finished.

Answer (score 0):

many can go wrong in that code:

```
url[0]
```

can be an empty string...

I would split that statement to:

```
Jsoup.connect(url[0])
```

+

```
.data("query", "Java")
                            .userAgent("Mozilla")
                            .cookie("auth", "token")
                            .timeout(10000)
```

- .post();

at least

Comment: But as you see i initalized url[0] to urll `url[0] = urll;` so url[0] has always some String on it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is somewhere inside your `try catch` block around the `Jsoup` code. Instead of `printStackTrace`, log something with `Log.e`, and then check your LogCat output.

Comment: Believe me, there is not Log that's displayed, just the URL Log before execution.

Comment: Don't know, perhaps that line is not correct :/ `document=new LoadDocument().execute(urll).get();`